# My PHP code doesn't display data from MySQL using array push then json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am a beginner in `JSON`, my question is why does my code which displays description (description is `medium text` type) does not output anything in the browser? but the title with type: `varchar 100` outputs normally?

my code `init.php`

```
<?php 

    $db_name = "webappdb";
    $user   = "root";
    $pass   = "";
    $server_name = "localhost";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($server_name, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    if (!$connection) {
        # code...
        echo "Error connection". mysqli_error();
    } else {
        // success
    }

 ?>
```

my code `iklanbaris.php` with displaying `titleIklanBaris`, it works..

```
<?php

    require "init.php";
    $sql_query1 = "SELECT * FROM iklan";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query1);
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array(
        'titleIklanBaris'=>$row[1]

        ));
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

[screenshot for the titleIklanBaris (it works display the data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9qIh.png)

my code `iklanbaris.php` with displaying `descriptionIklanBaris` (does not show anything)

```
<?php

    require "init.php";
    $sql_query1 = "SELECT * FROM iklan";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query1);
    $result = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        array_push($result,
        array(
        'descriptionIklanBaris'=>$row[2]

        ));
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

[screenshot for the descriptionIklanBaris, does not show the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTXPm.png)

and the last one my code mySQL query for creating the data I'm using:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.1.12
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Oct 02, 2016 at 12:48 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.16
-- PHP Version: 5.5.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `webappdb`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `iklan`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `iklan` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titleIklanBaris` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `descriptionIklanBaris` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `pengirimIklanBaris` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;



INSERT INTO `iklan` (`id`, `titleIklanBaris`, `descriptionIklanBaris`, `pengirimIklanBaris`) VALUES
(1, 'Sales Account Officer', 'Deskripsi Pekerjaan Melakukan kegiatan sales untuk mencapai target register baru layanan Jagoan Hosting & Beon.     Persyaratan Full time Pria / Wanita Maksimal 30 Tahun Pengalaman di bidang sales minimal 1 tahun Aktif berkomunikasi dan memiliki networking yang luas Mengerti penggunaan aplikasi yang berhubungan dengan internet Lancar berbahasa inggris (aktif & pasif) Berpengalaman sales di bidang IT (diutamakan) Berpenampilan menarik (diutamakan) Penempatan Kota Malang Benefit : Gaji pokok + Bonus + Tunjangan kesehatan', 'Beon Intermedia Group PT'),
(2, 'Sales Account Officer', 'Deskripsi Pekerjaan Melakukan kegiatan sales untuk mencapai target register baru layanan Jagoan Hosting & Beon.     Persyaratan Full time Pria / Wanita Maksimal 30 Tahun Pengalaman di bidang sales minimal 1 tahun Aktif berkomunikasi dan memiliki networking yang luas Mengerti penggunaan aplikasi yang berhubungan dengan internet Lancar berbahasa inggris (aktif & pasif) Berpengalaman sales di bidang IT (diutamakan) Berpenampilan menarik (diutamakan) Penempatan Kota Malang Benefit : Gaji pokok + Bonus + Tunjangan kesehatan', 'Beon Intermedia Group PT'),
(3, 'Sales Account Officer', 'Deskripsi Pekerjaan Melakukan kegiatan sales untuk mencapai target register baru layanan Jagoan Hosting & Beon.     Persyaratan Full time Pria / Wanita Maksimal 30 Tahun Pengalaman di bidang sales minimal 1 tahun Aktif berkomunikasi dan memiliki networking yang luas Mengerti penggunaan aplikasi yang berhubungan dengan internet Lancar berbahasa inggris (aktif & pasif) Berpengalaman sales di bidang IT (diutamakan) Berpenampilan menarik (diutamakan) Penempatan Kota Malang Benefit : Gaji pokok + Bonus + Tunjangan kesehatan', 'Beon Intermedia Group PT'),
(4, 'Sales Account Officer', 'Deskripsi Pekerjaan Melakukan kegiatan sales untuk mencapai target register baru layanan Jagoan Hosting & Beon.     Persyaratan Full time Pria / Wanita Maksimal 30 Tahun Pengalaman di bidang sales minimal 1 tahun Aktif berkomunikasi dan memiliki networking yang luas Mengerti penggunaan aplikasi yang berhubungan dengan internet Lancar berbahasa inggris (aktif & pasif) Berpengalaman sales di bidang IT (diutamakan) Berpenampilan menarik (diutamakan) Penempatan Kota Malang Benefit : Gaji pokok + Bonus + Tunjangan kesehatan', 'Beon Intermedia Group PT'),
(5, 'Business Consultant', 'GLI (Green Leaf Indonesia) Perusahaan Agribisnis yang sedang berkembang pesat sedang membutuhkan: Business Consultant (BC) Tanggung Jawab Pekerjaan : – Memperkenalkan program kerjasama tanam ke masyarakat – Memperkenalkan program penghijauan – Penempatan area kerja Malang dan sekitarnya Persyaratan Pengalaman : Pengalaman minimal 1 tahun di bidang salesmanship diutamakan Keahlian : – memiliki motivasi kerja tinggi, wawasan & jaringan luas, serta data base Kualifikasi : * Pria dan atau Wanita * Akhlaq baik dan jujur (ini yang paling utama) * Mau bekerja keras dan etos kerja tinggi * Diutamakan memiliki kendaraan dan SIM A/C * Pendidikan SMA sederajat atau lebih tinggi * Diutamakan domisili Malang, Jawa Timur ', 'Green Leaf Indonesia'),
(6, 'Business Consultant', 'GLI (Green Leaf Indonesia) Perusahaan Agribisnis yang sedang berkembang pesat sedang membutuhkan: Business Consultant (BC) Tanggung Jawab Pekerjaan : – Memperkenalkan program kerjasama tanam ke masyarakat – Memperkenalkan program penghijauan – Penempatan area kerja Malang dan sekitarnya Persyaratan Pengalaman : Pengalaman minimal 1 tahun di bidang salesmanship diutamakan Keahlian : – memiliki motivasi kerja tinggi, wawasan & jaringan luas, serta data base Kualifikasi : * Pria dan atau Wanita * Akhlaq baik dan jujur (ini yang paling utama) * Mau bekerja keras dan etos kerja tinggi * Diutamakan memiliki kendaraan dan SIM A/C * Pendidikan SMA sederajat atau lebih tinggi * Diutamakan domisili Malang, Jawa Timur ', 'Green Leaf Indonesia'),
(7, 'Business Consultant', 'GLI (Green Leaf Indonesia) Perusahaan Agribisnis yang sedang berkembang pesat sedang membutuhkan: Business Consultant (BC) Tanggung Jawab Pekerjaan : – Memperkenalkan program kerjasama tanam ke masyarakat – Memperkenalkan program penghijauan – Penempatan area kerja Malang dan sekitarnya Persyaratan Pengalaman : Pengalaman minimal 1 tahun di bidang salesmanship diutamakan Keahlian : – memiliki motivasi kerja tinggi, wawasan & jaringan luas, serta data base Kualifikasi : * Pria dan atau Wanita * Akhlaq baik dan jujur (ini yang paling utama) * Mau bekerja keras dan etos kerja tinggi * Diutamakan memiliki kendaraan dan SIM A/C * Pendidikan SMA sederajat atau lebih tinggi * Diutamakan domisili Malang, Jawa Timur ', 'Green Leaf Indonesia'),
(8, 'Business Consultant', 'GLI (Green Leaf Indonesia) Perusahaan Agribisnis yang sedang berkembang pesat sedang membutuhkan: Business Consultant (BC) Tanggung Jawab Pekerjaan : – Memperkenalkan program kerjasama tanam ke masyarakat – Memperkenalkan program penghijauan – Penempatan area kerja Malang dan sekitarnya Persyaratan Pengalaman : Pengalaman minimal 1 tahun di bidang salesmanship diutamakan Keahlian : – memiliki motivasi kerja tinggi, wawasan & jaringan luas, serta data base Kualifikasi : * Pria dan atau Wanita * Akhlaq baik dan jujur (ini yang paling utama) * Mau bekerja keras dan etos kerja tinggi * Diutamakan memiliki kendaraan dan SIM A/C * Pendidikan SMA sederajat atau lebih tinggi * Diutamakan domisili Malang, Jawa Timur ', 'Green Leaf Indonesia');
```

please help, why does not `iklanbaris.php` output anything when printing the content of `descriptionIklanBaris` ?

Comment: Try `echo json_encode($row)` for more info.

Comment: @Turtle the result is null, I have no idea about this..

Comment: There might be a fatal php error. Try adding `error_reporting(-1);` to the top of your init file. If that doesn't change anything, use `var_dump($row)` within your while loop to see what each row contains.

Comment: Try to access it using row['descriptionIklanBaris'] instead of row[2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and had the same problem as you, then changed the content of `descriptionIklanBaris` of all rows to 'test' and it worked fine, means you have a problem in the content

so, all you have to do is converting it to utf8 before pushing it to the array :)

here's the working code:

```
<?php

require "init.php";
$sql_query1 = "SELECT * FROM iklan";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query1);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    array_push($result,
    array(
    'descriptionIklanBaris'=>utf8_encode($row[2])

    ));
}

echo json_encode($result);

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: If you're using utf8_encode for your own data, you're definitely doing it wrong. Just make sure your data in the db is correctly encoded and you speak the same language as your connection expects. More info, read this: http://melp.nl/2011/01/about-mysql-utf-8-and-saving-headaches/